# Is there a way to have snipping tool available for windows 7 with .NET Framework 1.1

Tags: windows-7, windows

Is there a way to have snipping tool available for windows 7 with .NET Framework 1.1?

I need help without changing the .NET Framework

Comment: Snipping Tool is already by default a feature of Windows 7.  What exactly is your question?  Why can't you install .NET Framework 3.5?

Comment: Snipping Tool is not at all related to .NET Framework.

Comment: Installing a later version of net framework does not remove previous versions, update to 3.5. Go to Control Panel>Programs and Features>Turn Windows Features on or Off>>>Tick "Microsoft NetFramework 3.5" box, click OK, it will install it.

Answer (score 3):

Snipping Tool come as a default application from Windows 7 onwards. You can open the tool by hitting start and search for 'snipping tool' in the search bar of start.

Answer (score 1):

The snipping tool is a feature that the Windows 7 system has by default. If your system does not have this feature for some reason, you can re-download it on the official website.

By the way, I still recommend that you update your Net framework. The new version optimizes the previous drawbacks and provides better features.